# Centos 8 symlink to users's `.ssh` folder

Tags: ssh, centos, gitlab, centos-8

I'm following [this guide](https://blog.xiaket.org/2017/exposing.ssh.port.in.dockerized.gitlab-ce.html) to setup some kind of ssh proxy for gitlab.

## this is how ti doesn't work

When I create symlink like in that blog post I'm not able to ssh into server. This is how symlink is created.

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 git  git     28 Apr  4 19:39 /home/git/.ssh -> /opt/gitlab/gitlab/data/.ssh
```

here is the output of `/opt/gitlab/gitlab/data/.ssh`

```
-rw-------.  1 git  git  2768 Apr  4 19:03 authorized_keys
-rw-------.  1 git  git     0 Apr  4 19:03 authorized_keys.lock
-rw-------.  1 git  git   579 Apr  4 16:21 authorized_keys_proxy
-rw-------.  1 git  git  2610 Apr  4 16:21 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--.  1 git  git   179 Apr  4 19:57 known_hosts
```

and output of `/opt/gitlab/gitlab/data/`

```
drwx------.  2 git            git    119 Apr  4 19:57 .ssh
```

## this is how it works

When I copy all those files from `/opt/gitlab/gitlab/data/.ssh` to `/home/users/git/.ssh` then **ssh works correctly**. It looks like symlinks are not correctly resloved.

## what should I do?

Please is it somehow possible to use symlinks inside user's `.ssh` directory and have working ssh?

I'm using centos 8 with selinux enabled.

## EDIT:

I've resolved it looking into `/var/log/secure` log. It states `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /opt/gitlab` so I've changed permissions on that folder to `chown git:git /opt/gitlab` and it's working :D

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Do you get any error messages? What happens if you turn on verbose mode with `-vvv`? Then do you see any relevant output?

Comment: You can move your explanation of the fix into a separate answer, and then after a while (24 hours?) you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer. That way this will show up as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in permissions of parent folder as I found it in `/var/log/secure` log.

with following change `chown git:git /opt/gitlab` it's working as expected.